# BGE: How to make a minimap that shows the player's position?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, logic-bricks

How would I go about making a map that shows the player's position in world? 
Similar to GTA types of games.

Comment: You'll need to create an extra camera and have it parented to the player. next create a split-screen.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TtTBGSOii4. is a video on split screens.

Comment: You can produce a simple mini-map by rendering a specific camera view to an active texture, as demonstrated in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgXAv9csJu0#t=1m21s